# https is not serving content even after ssl setup, but http does

Tags: apache, docker, redirect, webserver, docker-machine

I have a docker container running Jupyter notebook on port 8000 on a RHEL 7 server, and when I access it over http://server-name:8000, it seems to be perfectly fine.

However, when I tried to configure ssl certs on apache web server, content is not being served on https

my config file is like below.

```
Listen 443 https
<VirtualHost *:443>  
    ServerName server.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cerfile.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/Keyfile.key
    ProxyPass / https://server.com:8000/tree
    ProxyPassReverse / https://server.com/8000/tree                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
</VirtualHost>
```

> I am not able to access https://server.com:8000/tree individually,
>   however i am able to access http://server.com:8000/tree

And its not that my certificates are not working, I am able to access https://server.com when I remove ProxyPass in above config.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>  
    ServerName server.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cerfile.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/Keyfile.key                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
</VirtualHost>
```

I am not sure of why my content is not loading under https, can someone explain me this?

Error receiving when trying to reach https://server-name:8000/tree

> This site can’t be reached server-name took too long to
>   respond. Try:
>
> Checking the connection Checking the proxy and the firewall
>   ERR_TIMED_OUT

Comment: What error do you get when trying to connect with https?

Comment: @NicolaBenaglia ERR_Timed_out.. unable to reach server

Comment: If you enter the container, is port 443 open? Is it exposed?

Comment: @NicolaBenaglia yes Nicola.. it is open, I even mapped container 443 to 8000.But it is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick, Seems like Jupyter has standard proxying config.
[Reference:](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/367)

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /api/kernels/ ws://server:8000/api/kernels/
ProxyPassReverse /api/kernels https://server:8000/api/kernels/
ProxyPass / https://server:8000/
ProxyPassReverse / https://server:8000/
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your conf your reverse proxy is listening on port 443 not on 8080 that's why you are not able to access the app via 8080 when proxypass is there. if you want access the app via https for port 8080 try the below conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>  
    ServerName server.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cerfile.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/Keyfile.key
    ProxyPass / https://server.com:8000/tree
    ProxyPassReverse / https://server.com/8000/tree                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: port 8080? does it listen to port 8080 by default for reverse proxy?

Comment: In your question you mentioned that  "Error receiving when trying to reach https://server-name:8000/tree" to resolve that you can use above http conf.
By default http listen on 80 and https on 443.

Comment: but it was 8000 right? why 8080? i tried with both 8000 and 8080... it seems to be not working..